# What is the order of parameter (lat/long) in python UTM package for conversion into x, y coordinate?

Tags: python, utm, pyproj

Currently, I am trying to convert (lat, long) into (x, y) coordinates in Python. There are some packages like pyproj or utm to do that. For example:

```
import utm
lat = 41.8836718276551
lon = 12.4877775603346
x, y, zn, zl = utm.from_latlon(float(lat), float(lon))
```

My question is that what is the order of the parameter? is it (lat, lon) or (lon, lat)? Even If I use pyproj to do the same conversion, then what will be the order?

Comment: The source has `def from_latlon(latitude, longitude, force_zone_number=None, force_zone_letter=None):` Note that using 'long' as a variable name is fraught (type name) -- use 'lon' or 'longitude' instead.

Answer (score 4):

For `pyproj` you should be mindful of [axis order changes](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6).

If you want it to always be in the `lon, lat` order, you should specify it when creating the transformer.

For example:

```py
from pyproj import Transformer
transformer = Transformer.from_crs(..., ..., always_xy=True)
```

Otherwise, you should inspect the axis order of your CRS as shown in the [getting started](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html) documentation.